# App Submission to the app store built for ios7 not 8

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have created my new application and it's ready to be submitted using IOS 7.1 . It's not yet optimized to be compatible with IOS 8. My question is until when i can keep submitting apps built for iOS 7, keeping in mind that iOS 8 was officially launched yesterday

Comment: Only Apple knows that answer, but maybe soms month until they make some part of the iOS 8 SDK mandatory.

Comment: @rckoenes so until further notice from apple, we can still upload apps built with iOS 7 right ? and they will tell us in advance of course right?

Comment: Yes you can still submit iOS 7 build apps. Apple often posts a message on there developers news page, I suggest you check it regularly: https://developer.apple.com/news/

Comment: thank you cheers post it as answer so i can accept it @rckoenes

Comment: "64-bit Requirement for App Updates

April 8, 2015
As a reminder, beginning June 1, 2015 app updates submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code. For more information, read the 64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch."